# Videoprocessor with custom horizontal sampling

Tags: hardware, graphics, video, atari-st

I have a variety of videoprocessors (Micomsoft Framemeister, Micomsoft SC-512N1-L/DVI, Sync Strike) to help me get the best possible RGB picture out of my retro computers/consoles.

However one issue has always stumped me:

- Some retro computers/consoles output with an unusually wide horizontal resolution (for example, Atari ST Medium resolution is 640x200)
- Most scalers have the horizontal sampling rate locked at 720 pixels
- Since there is no integer divide between the sampling rate of 720 pixels and the console's horizontal resolution of 640 pixels, these images always look terrible

What I'm looking for:

- A scaler that either has a customisable (or fixed but very high) horizontal sampling rate

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: An uncorrected scan at the wrong horizontal rate is going to look terrible, but depending upon what sort of filtering the scanner is doing it might be possible to take the lousy-looking scan and reconstruct a good image from it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to apply Nyquist Theorem here (as long as I sample at greater than 2X the source sample rate, I should be able to recreate the original perfectly in post-process).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Open Source Scan Converter (OSSC) supports custom [horizontal sample rates](http://junkerhq.net/xrgb/index.php/OSSC#Horizontal_samplerate), even Amiga's [PAL:Super-HiRes (1440×283)](https://www.videogameperfection.com/forums/topic/advanced-timing-settings-for-amiga/) mode.

Comment: Awesome! I've been following the OSSC but wasn't aware it could do this. Thanks!